# Передать параметр в массив для определенной страницы Angular

Tags: angular2, angular, angular-routing

Всем привет. Недавно начал работать с angular и у меня возник вопрос.
Есть компонент с массивом "mySlideOptions", в котором находится определенный набор параметров.

```js
import {Component,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {TopUploadersService} from './top-uploaders.service'
import {apiRoutes} from '../../app-constants';
import {HelperService} from '../../services/helper.service'


{
  selector: 'app-user-list',
  templateUrl: './user-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-list.component.css'
  }
  export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {

    mySlideImages = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    mySlideOptions = {
      items: 6,
      dots: true,
      nav: false,
      owl2row: true,
      margin: 30,
      mouseDrag: false,
      responsive: {
        0: {
          items: 2
        },
        600: {
          items: 4
        },
        1000: {
          items: 6
        }
      }
    };


    UserImage;
    userPhoto: string;
    uploaders;
    constructor(protected topUploadersService: TopUploadersService, protected helperService: HelperService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
      this.getTopUploaders();

    }
    getTopUploaders() {

      this.topUploadersService.getTopUploaders().then((resp) => {
        this.uploaders = resp;
        console.log(this.uploaders);
        for (let entry of this.uploaders) {
          entry.UserPic = this.ProfilePicPath(entry.UserId);
        }
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
    }


    ProfilePicPath(userId) {
      this.UserImage = {};
      this.UserImage.objectURL = apiRoutes.users.updateUserImage.replace('{UserId}', userId);
      return this.getImagePath(this.UserImage);
    }
    getImagePath(item) {

      if (item.objectURL && item.objectURL.indexOf) {
        this.userPhoto = item.objectURL;
        return this.userPhoto;
      }
      return item.objectURL;
    }

    getFormatedPostSize(postSize) {
      return this.helperService.getFormatedPostSizeMBtoTB(postSize);

    }


  }
```

Хочу выводить этот компонент на двух разных страницах Home и /profile
Для страницы profile и всё что будет за ней например /profile/1/2 нужно что бы значение owl2row в этом массиве было true, для остальных страниц false.
Подскажите как будет правильнее всего это реализовать. Вывожу так:

```html
<div class="container-fluid user-list" *ngIf="uploaders">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Top Uploaders</h2>
    <owl-carousel [options]="mySlideOptions" [items]="images" [carouselClasses]="['owl-theme', 'sliding']">
      <div class="item" *ngFor="let uploader of uploaders;let i = index">
        <div [routerLink]="['/profile', uploader.UserId]" class="user-block">
          <div class="img_user"><img src="{{ProfilePicPath(uploader.UserId)}}" alt=""></div>
          <div class="info-user">
            <p class="name">{{uploader.Username}}</p>
            <p class="files"><i class="fas fa-download"></i>{{uploader.UploadedFiles}} Files</p>
            <p class="download"><i class="fas fa-paperclip"></i>{{getFormatedPostSize(uploader.UploadedFilesSizeMb)}} </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </owl-carousel>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: отформатируйте пожалуйста код - иначе минус поставлю. Проверку сделайте на урл из роутера да и все дела

Comment: А можно подробней?

Comment: инжектите `Router` сервис, у него есть свойство `url`, сеттите свойство `owl2row: this.router.url.startsWith('/profile')`

Answer (score 0):

Router сервис, у него есть свойство url, сеттите свойство owl2row: this.router.url.startsWith('/profile')
Это сработало для меня. Спасибо